# Why is this answer not a "Not An Answer"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I raised a Not An Answer flag for this answer: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259537/5779732*

Following is the body of the answer:

> Just download the itk framework, and itk document along with the gdcm framework, and cmake to compile itk for xcode.
>
> Follow the instructions in the itk document you should be able to read the image atleast the meta data but turning it to uiimage requires some coding.

The answerer is asking the OP to download the framework, compile it, read the document and follow the instructions to solve the problem in hand.

There is no mention how this will fix the problem of OP. This is just tool-kit recommendation. No source code provided for better understanding. No specific section in documentation mentioned in answer. No names of important classes/methods mentioned at least to give a hint.

This answer looks NAA to me; this is better as comment instead.

My flag was declined as below:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why this answer is not a "Not An Answer"?

Before flagging an answer, I thought about flagging question as Off Topic or Too Broad. But, that is not the case. Question is not asking for tool kit. Have a look at accepted answer. It do recommend the toolkit, but it also provides more useful details to use it.

Comment: There are a *lot* of meta posts that discuss when the NAA flag should be used, please research them first.

Comment: I did @HansPassant. This is mistake from my side flagging incorrectly. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the answer recommends a library. That doesn't automatically make it not an answer.

Go back to the question. It says:

> Does anyone know how I can extract the pixel data from a DICOM file and pass it to an image viewer on iOS?

Now, the answer, paraphrased, says "download the framework, compile it like this, and follow the instructions to read the image data".

So…that's an answer. If you think it isn't a *useful* or *complete* answer, you should downvote it. No one has downvoted it.

Comment: DICOM is bit complicated protocol and most new-comers face problems in understanding the concept and terminologies. The same reflects while asking questions about problem. I was not the exception when I started with it. I will say the question is good (refer explanation in my question) and can be answered very well. Accepted answer is good example. I have also mentioned in my question that "that answer" better suits as a comment.

Comment: The "not an answer" flag does ***not*** mean "I don't think is a good answer" or "This answer is incomplete". It means "this post does not even resemble an attempt to answer the question that was asked, and a moderator needs to delete it". Again, if you think the answer is not helpful, lacking information, or whatever, then downvote it. @amit

Comment: I remember I read a post on meta that explains what is NAA with an example of images of "Apple". I am trying to find it. can you please point me to that post?

Comment: @AmitJoshi https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: The "apples" post is talking about "link-only" answers. This clearly wasn't a link-only answer. It didn't have any links. All of the "apple" guidance has been incorporated into the question that I closed this one as a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMyers. The links explains it well. This is problem on my side. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: By the way, I have also flagged one other answer of same question for same reason. I just tried to retract the flag now but the button is not available. How should I proceed with it?

Comment: Ohhhh.... That flag was accepted as helpful. May be that is why I cannot retract it anymore.